# Nagios core GUI/UI fails to open after nagios-4.4.6-4 to 4.4.9-1 update on Rhel8

Tags: redhat, monitoring, nagios, graphical-user-interface

Nagios core GUI/UI fails to open after nagios-4.4.6-4 to 4.4.9-1 update on Rhel8 vm.

Whoops! Error: Could not read host and service status information!

Nothing in /var/log/nagios/nagios.log.

/sbin/nagios -v /etc/nagios/nagios.cfg doesn't report any errors.

Comment: Is the service running (error message suggests it is not)? Can you try to start it by hand, not with the service manager, and see what it prints to a shell?

Comment: Nagios is running but it takes several seconds to start, before update it started in a few seconds.

Comment: Then, while it is running like that, do you still have the described problem?

Comment: Yes still same problem

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this solution from Nagios forum ? : https://support.nagios.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=49019#p254150

> Apache does not know the location of the cgi.cfg since it's not in the
> default location as expected by Nagios. Added env var
> NAGIOS_CGI_CONFIG with the new location.
>
> See https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nag ... igcgi.html